# show newly installed font in jasper report from grails in pdf format

Tags: grails, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.5.0 and grails 2.1.1

I wanted to use 'Canterbury' font for some of the texts in my report in pdf format, so i assigned that font to my desired texts using iReport designer. I also went to tools->option menu of the iReport designer and installed the font. And then made a jar extension by clicking 'Export as extension' of that font.

I copied the created extension file and pasted to my application's classpath with no success.

The problem is, when i run the report from my application the pdf report is showing the normal font instead of 'Canterbury' in all of the texts.

I also followed the link http://javaskeleton.blogspot.sg/2010/12/embedding-fonts-into-pdf-generated-by.html
with no success.

What did i miss out? any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your jar file of font in lib folder of grails application. Also you need to install your font in system where your server is running. 
After that you should write this syntax in you iReport's xml file below property .

```
<style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="yourFontFamilyNameInJarFile" fontSize="10" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/>
```

Here is a snippet image of philospher font ,I have used.

[image]

**Note :** Do not add pdfFontName , it will give you error because this is deprecated now.

Comment: where should i write the style in xml:<style name="Sans_Normal" isDefault="true" fontName="yourFontFamilyNameInJarFile" fontSize="10" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/> and clarify me about your note please

Comment: Below this syntax `<property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>`

Comment: Everything is done and tested. but no success. i am running into local server. i also checked that the font is installed in my pc

Comment: can you provide me your jar file and and also write syntax of style tag. Also did you test it in ireport?

Comment: this is my style tag syntax <style name="Canterbury" isDefault="true" fontName="Canterbury" fontSize="10" pdfEncoding="Cp1252" isPdfEmbedded="true"/> and i tested in my ireport. how to provide jar file to you?

Comment: Send to me at : mabtestflight@gmail.com. send your jar file and font(ttf).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38711/discussion-between-user1791574-and-rashedul-rubel)

Comment: I have sent you the mail with the jar and ttf

Comment: @user1791574 you have shown a details way for worked it out. Although Rashedul.Rubel's problem is completely similar to me, this process is not working for me. But I have followed all the way you have shown. Can you please help me on this, please !?