# Bold style doesn't work in pdf output

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports

I'm building a few report using *iReport 5.1.0* and *JasperReports 5.0.0*. Now my trouble is that bold style is not appearing in pdf output. If I have stylized text (for example, `"<b>My Text</b>"`), the bold parts appear bold in the report's output, but not in the pdf. The only way I can get bold in pdf is to force the pdf font for that element to be a bold font (pdfFontName="Helvetica-Bold" for example), but that bolds the entire string and does not allow me to control it via the style markup `<b>`.

I'm exporting the pdf file in this way:

```
JRPdfExporter exp = new JRPdfExporter();
exp.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME, namefileToExport);
exp.exportReport();
```

How can I do?

Comment: You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: You can look at [Style a text field in JasperReports](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8135215/876298) post

Answer (score 7):

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts/6.0.0

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports-fonts -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

adding this dependency to the pom.xml should be enough to fix the problem

Answer (score 2):

I have just had the same problem only I used styled markup, not html and [this](http://blog.itcrowd.pl/2013/11/bold-style-missing-in-jasperreports.html) solution helped me.

I only added these 4 lines before generating the report to embed fonts into pdf:

```
DefaultJasperReportsContext context = DefaultJasperReportsContext.getInstance();
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name", "DejaVu Sans");
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded", "true");
JRPropertiesUtil.getInstance(context).setProperty("net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name", "DejaVu Sans");
```

And then added a new dependency to the maven configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -1):

In your text field select markup as `html` and write your text like this.

```
"<b>" + "My" + "</b>" + "Text"
```

For install new font you can follow this link.
[install new font](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218380/show-newly-installed-font-in-jasper-report-from-grails-in-pdf-format/19218876#19218876)

Comment: Then you need to put jar file of font.