# How to make Jasper use an extra font added to grails war?

Tags: java, grails, fonts, jasper-reports

I'm trying to add some extra fonts to my application war to use them with Jasper Reports plugin.
I've followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6712081/1164954) answer to add font files to my application and made it work with absolute paths for font files. However, I can't make it work with relative paths, so I have to have a different `jasper_fonts.xml` config file for different deployments, which is no good.

I have an `appname/web-app/fonts` directory in my grails project which is deployed as `appname/fonts` in Tomcat6, but if I set font path in `jasper_fonts.xml` to `fonts/font.ttf` I get an `InputStreamNotFound` exception. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: are you using ireport to make your jrxml file?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19218380/show-newly-installed-font-in-jasper-report-from-grails-in-pdf-format/19218876#19218876
follow this link to set your font in ireport.

Comment: @user1791574, that might help, but it's not exactly what I need. The described method requires installation of fonts into system where app is deployed and I want a fully operational war. The problem is in relative paths.

Comment: Have you installed desired font in your system ? Also post your full stacktrace to understand problem in better way...

Comment: @user1791574, No, I haven't installed them and that is the reason for the question. I need jasper to use font files specified in `jasper_fonts.xml`. When I specify absolute paths to fonts, it works, but I can't make it work with relative paths.

Comment: you do not need to provide absolute path. Just install your font in system. are you using linux or windows to develop your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40800/discussion-between-svz-and-user1791574)